# How to iterate nested JSON response and display as ag-grid table in angular 6

Tags: angular

Need to display JSON response as a grid.  I need to iterate and display as rows (even the nested details should be displayed in rows) .provide suggestions for angular 6.

In below mock response, data has multiple segments(segLst). Each SegLst should be displayed as a row in grid. Also, SegLst has multiple legs(legLst). Each legLst also be displayed as rows under SegLst.
i.e.,
Display SegLst(where, segId:1) in row 1
Display LegLst(legNb:1) in row 2
Display LegLst(legNb:2) in row 3
Display SegLst(segId:2) in row 4
Display LegLst(legNb:3) in row 5
Display SegLst(segId:3) in row 6
Display LegLst(legNb:4) in row 7

Mock data:

```
{
"Data": [
        {
            "emplId": "124",
            "rotnId": "1",
            "Status": "flwn",
            "SegLst": [
                {
                    "segId": "1",
                    "segFrm": "bse",
                    "segCnt": 120,
                    "legLst": [
                        {
                            "legNb": "1",
                            "legId": "11",
                            "fltNum": "832",
                            "From": "ATL",
                            "To": "HNL"
                        },
                        {
                            "legNb": "2",
                            "legId": "12",
                            "fltNum": "836",
                            "From": "HNL",
                            "To": "DTW"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "segId": "2",
                    "segFrm": "bse",
                    "segCnt": 130,
                    "legLst": [
                        {
                            "legNb": "3",
                            "legId": "13",
                            "fltNum": "902",
                            "From": "DTW",
                            "To": "NRT"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "segId": "3",
                    "segFrm": "bse",
                    "segCnt": 130,
                    "legLst": [
                        {
                            "legNb": "4",
                            "legId": "14",
                            "fltNum": "800",
                            "From": "MSP",
                            "To": "ATL"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please provide your mock data which is nested

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? @swank

Answer (score 0):

We can create a model and store the iterated values into it.
Here model should contain all fields of nested lists.